# Arc length of a curve between coordinates

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find the arc length of the curve defined by:
$x = t^3, y = t^2$ from (0,0) to (8,4).

I wasn't sure exactly what the $b$ and $a$ should be from the points, I assumed it was 0 .. 8 since the curve went from the origin out to x=8 (I did try other ranges but all produced incorrect results).

I went ahead using the arc length formula as follows:

$$\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b \sqrt{9t^4 + 4t^2} dt$$
$$\frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{1}{18}\frac{2}{3}(9t^2 + 4)^\frac{3}{2}\right)]_0^8$$
$$\frac{1}{216}(9t^2 + 4)^\frac{3}{2}]_0^8$$
$$\frac{1}{216}(580)^\frac{3}{2} - \frac{1}{216}(4)^\frac{3}{2}$$

But the answer in my the book is:

$$\frac{8}{27}(10\sqrt{10} -1)$$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The limits are wrong: what is $(t^3,t^2)$ when $t=8$?  And the integral is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limits should be from the starting $t$-value to the ending $t$-value; you are using the $x$-values.

As you move along this curve from $(0,0)$ to $(8,4)$, $t$ is moving from $0$ to $2$.

Comment: Hmm that's what I did use for the integration. Why is mine wrong, if I differentiate it, I get that, i.e.: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate+1%2F27%289t%5E2+%2B+4%29%5E%283%2F2%29 (the extra 1/8 is just the 1/b-a)

Comment: Oh OK! I was confused by the other thing. It appeared like the antiderivative was not right, but I see what you have now.